# Como gravar dados de duas colunas de uma tabela usando select?

Tags: php, mysql

Olá, estou usando um Select para pegar dados da tabela Marcas, e gravar o código e o nome da marca quando cadastrar o produto, mas não estou conseguindo gravar os dados das duas simultaneamente, ou seja só consigo gravar o código ou o nome da marca, se altera-los no VALUE.

O meu SELECT esta assim:

```
        <label>Selecione a Marca:</label><br />
        <select name="codmarca">
        <?php
        include '../conexao.php';
        $select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM marca");
        while($res = mysql_fetch_array($select)){
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $marca = $res['codigo'];?>"><?php echo $marca = $res['nome_marca'];?></option>
        <?php } ?>
        </select>
```

E dessa forma eu só consigo gravar o código, pois é ele que esta no VALUE no momento.

Como faço para gravar o 'codigo' e o 'nome_marca' ao mesmo tempo usando o select, ou não tem como?

Agradeço desde já a atenção de todos ao meu problema.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode concatenar o valor do código e do nome da marca e colocá-los no VALUE.
Ao resgatar o valor do atributo VALUE, fazer um split e gravá-los nos campos desejados.

```
<label>Selecione a Marca:</label><br />
    <select name="codmarca">
    <?php
    include '../conexao.php';
    $select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM marca");
    while($res = mysql_fetch_array($select)){
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $marca = $res['codigo'] . '#' . $res['nome_marca'];?>"><?php echo $marca = $res['nome_marca'];?></option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>
```

Para o código acima o valor do atributo VALUE ficará: CÓDIGO#NOME_MARCA.
Quando você for resgatar esse valor, faça o split da string CODIGO#NOME_MARCA:

```
list($codigo, $nome) = explode("#", $data);
echo $codigo; // CÓDIGO DA MARCA
echo $nome; // NOME DA MARCA
```

Comment: Eu preciso recupera pelo menos o nome_marca em outra pagina.
Desculpe E.Thomas, mas eu sou leigo nessa parte de explode, essa parte do list eu insiro onde? Na pagina onde vou recuperar os dados, ou na mesmas pagina do SELECT?

Comment: Murilo, o explode é do PHP, conforme o seu exemplo. Imagine uma string '3#PORSCHE'. Quando é feito: explode('#', '3#PORSCHE') o retorno é um array com dois elementos. O comando list coloca o valor do primeiro índice (3) na variável $codigo e o valor do segundo índice (PORSCHE) na variável $nome. Você deve enviar esses dados  e tratá-los no arquivo .php que insere as informações no banco de dados, através de um POST ou GET.

Answer (score 1):

A solução do E.Thomas é válida.

Mas acho que pode usar o próprio MySQL para isso.

**Utilize somente o `codigo`como value:**

```
<option value="<?php echo $marca = $res['codigo'];?>"><?php echo $marca = $res['nome_marca'];?></option>
```

**Para gravar (`INSERT`) utilize algo similar a:**

```
INSERT INTO TABELA(nome) VALUES (SELECT nome_marca FROM marca WHERE codigo = ?)
```

> O `?` deve ser o valor que obteve o option.

**Resumindo seria:**

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO TABELA(nome) VALUES (SELECT nome marca FROM marca WHERE codigo = $_POST['codmarca'])");
```

> O mysql_query é obsoleto, apenas usei  por ser um exemplo rápido e prático de entender!

Comment: Pelo que entendi ele não conseguia utilizar a tag option para armazenar mais de um valor para posterior recuperação. Mas se a ideia dele é só gravar dois dados ao mesmo tempo no banco de dados, sua resposta é a correta.